# how to resolva module not found error cython

Tags: python, tensorflow

while running the code i am getting the following error

```
(tfpose) C:\Users\dharma\Desktop\tf-pose-estimation>pip3 install pycocotools
Collecting pycocotools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/84/9a07b1095fd8555ba3f3d519517c8743c2554a245f9476e5e39869f948d2/pycocotools-2.0.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\dharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kyxs7psk\pycocotools\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kyxs7psk\pycocotools\
```

Comment: pip3 install Cython